# Hypothesys testing, t test for one sample

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, spss

I wanted to test following hypothesys: "We suppose that math professors use new technology to make learning easier". I made survey with following questions

1. I use computer programs such as Geogebra, desmos etc. every lesson.
2. I use interactive tables,  3d printers. etc.
   Possible answers are:
   I completely agree, I mostly agree, I'm undecided, I mostly disagree, I don't agree at all.

What is the best possible way to test if my hypothesys is true in SPSS? I graded answers from -2(I don't agree at all) to  2 (I completely agree). I was thinking of using one sample t test for arithmetic variable X which is arithmetic mean of answers on given two questions. And put testing value to be 1.

Size of survey is $100$ persons. Normality assumption can be neglected?  Any advice?

Please tell me if I am not clear enough and you need more detail to help me.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Mark. This is neither a statistical nor a scientific hypothesis.  You need to begin by thinking about how your survey responses might be related to the questions you are asking.  For (much) more about hypotheses, please [search our site.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123287/how-to-choose-the-null-and-alternative-hypothesis) There are many other subquestions lurking here, too, such as how to grade the answers and how to test whatever hypothesis you might formulate.  We can't answer such a broad question.  See our [help] for more about how this site works.

Comment: @whuber. If i have ordinal variable X with 5 levels: 1 2 3 4 5 and data is not normal What is the best way to test if X >3?

Comment: No variable with five levels will have a Normal distribution.  Furthermore, "$X\gt 3$" is not a hypothesis: it's a *prediction.*

Comment: @whuber Ok. Let's suppose X is countionuos variable and i have100 observed values of X. If i want to test hypothesys that proportion of $X>3$ is grreater that 0.8. Can I use binomial test in SPSS?

Comment: Sure: that's a standard application of binomial tests and I am confident SPSS can carry it out.